# nested arrays and strings in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to figure out nested arrays, particularly of the multi dimensional type.  I've gone through two articles on them and are getting tripped up when the iteration is checking for strings.

```
# Array - 
more_nested_array = [["hello", ["world", "new york"]], ["love", "ruby"]]

# Iteration-
more_nested_array.each do |element|
 element.each do |inner_element|
    if inner_element.is_a?(Array)
      inner_element.each do |third_layer_element|
     end
   end
  end
end
```

So it is using the if statement because supposedly in some iteration there are strings.  This reference to strings is confusing me since it looks like it's just a bunch of arrays.  Can someone explain please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## NoMethodError otherwise

The check is needed because the loops are hard-coded for this given tree (or nested arrays, if you prefer).

Removing the check :

```
more_nested_array = [["hello", ["world", "new york"]], ["love", "ruby"]]

# Iteration-
more_nested_array.each do |element|
  element.each do |inner_element|
    inner_element.each do |third_layer_element|
      puts third_layer_element
    end
  end
end
```

outputs:

```
undefined method `each' for "hello":String (NoMethodError)
```

because not every `inner_element` is an array or responds to `each`.

## Recursive version

With this kind of structure, it would be preferrable to write a recursive method in order to parse the tree, instead of hard-coding the tree depth and node classes.

```
more_nested_array = [["hello", ["world", "new york"]], ["love", "ruby"]]

def parse_tree(node, current_depth = 0)
  if node.respond_to?(:each)
    node.each do |child|
      parse_tree(child, current_depth + 1)
    end
  else
    puts "Found #{node.inspect} at depth #{current_depth}"
  end
end

parse_tree(more_nested_array)
```

It outputs:

```
Found "hello" at depth 2
Found "world" at depth 3
Found "new york" at depth 3
Found "love" at depth 2
Found "ruby" at depth 2
```

Comment: You could also say _"because not every `inner_element` responds to `each`"_ (and a check via `respond_to?` might be preferable to a type check)

Comment: Ok, I guess what is throwing me is the way the array is written. The way I read it is, the most outer edge brackets seem to be the parent array.  Within, there are two child arrays but in the first child array has it's own child (or grandchild of the original parent). i.e. ["hello", ["world", "new york"]].

Comment: @stuartambient this is not a tree, there is no parent-child-relationship. `more_nested_array`'s first element is an array and it contains two elements: a string `"hello"` and an(other) array `["world", "new york"]`. Maybe you are under the impression that arrays may only contain one "type" of object. That is not the case in Ruby. An array can contain any object: `[1, nil, :foo, "bar", {a: 2}]` is a valid array.

Comment: @Stefan: The OP's nested array can certainly be seen as a Tree whose leaves are strings, but it might not necessarily help to understand the structure.

Comment: @Stefan, Okay that shed some light.  I see the difference now and it makes sense.  I was aware that arrays can hold various objects in them so not sure what I was expecting to see.  What I was doing was attempting to separate and count using the brackets, how many actual arrays were in there.  I'm going to look for a few more example so it's hammered in, thanks!

Comment: @Eric Duminil A similar example from another site, basically the same method used a tree diagram- music_library = [["Adele", ["19", ["Day Dreamer", "Best for Last"]], ["21", ["Rolling in the Deep", "Rumor Has It"]]], ["Beyonce", ["4", ["1 + 1", "Countdown"]], ["Beyonce", ["Haunted", "Pretty Hurts"]]]]  I believe the strings  in the first array, 21/Rolling in the Deep and Rumor has it.  I believe the if / else is only needed for the 2nd iteration.

Answer (score -1):

`"hello"` is a string, which is being stored along with arrays such as `["world", "new york"]`, that's why the code is ignoring the strings since strings doesn't have `each` method defined on them.

Comment: "strings are iterable as well" Are you sure about that?

Comment: String consists of characters, do they not?

Comment: _"the code is ignoring the strings since strings are iterable"_ – Could you explain that?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, when you iterate over a string - you get characters. Is it not the case in ruby?

Comment: Sure, there is for example `String#each_char`. But why do you conclude that the code ignores strings because of that?

Comment: I'm guessing because he doesn't want to split string any further. Splitting "hello" into 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' won't make much sense.

Comment: "strings are iterable" in Python, not by default in Ruby. You need to define how you want to enumerate them (`each_char`, `each_byte`, `each_line`, ...)

Comment: @hspandher It might be enlightening for you to [actually run OP's code](https://repl.it/JEBw) and then see what happens when you take out the code that makes it ignore strings.

Comment: @EricDuminil Yeah I kind of realized that, it's been a while since I used ruby. Anyway the only apparent reason the code is avoiding strings is to avoid calling `each` block on it.

Comment: @JordanRunning I would have if I could. Sadly I'm in office with no sudo permissions or ruby build installed.

Comment: @JordanRunning Well thanks. I didn't think of that. Anyway irrespective of whether strings are iterable or not, the crux remains the same that the developer doesn't wants to run `each` method on strings.

Comment: @hspandher I'm so sorry, I totally misread your answer! You were saying _"the code is using `if` because otherwise it would also iterate the strings"_ and I was reading _"the code doesn't skip the strings because of the `if` but because they are iterable"_ (which didn't make any sense)

Comment: @Stefan No problem, unless you're being sarcastic :)

Comment: I'm not (and the downvote isn't mine). Unfortunately, your conclusion is still wrong, because `String` doesn't respond to `each`, so without the `if`, you would get a `NoMethodError`. The code would not iterate the characters.